Not able to launch the android on beeware

when installing new versions error is occured. what to do at this point.
Not able to launch on both beeware emulator and by doing on my personal android device by usb debugging. can you please help me in resolving this problem . I am a newbie using beeware for the first time.

Please do not post terminal output as screenshot, this is text, so lease just copy and paste it into your question and format it as code. Have you checked the log file mentioned in the terminal output?
